# Does CharField with no defined max_length in serializer accept unlimit character?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-serializer

For example, I have a serializer like this

```
class Question(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = serializers.CharField()
    body = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
```

For **description** field, I don't specific max_length attribute, so it accept lots of characters, but does it really unlimit?
And what is the different between **description** field and **body** field above? Does they the same?

Comment: no u have to define max_length

Comment: you only need to define max_length in models, cus it talk with db, the serializer don't talk with db

Comment: how you can save a object after validating serializers?

Comment: models.objects.create(**validated_data). that's it

Comment: sorry. i didn't understand your question. you are right

Answer (score 2):

Without `max_length`, the serializer will not make any validation about the length of sent data. But you can make validation after the (de)serialization before saving data for example...

For difference between `description` and `body`, the body seems to take arg named `style`, it is for rendering purpose of the field.

If you are just specific question about argument, you can read the documentation: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#field-styles

Comment: So if I input 10000 character in `description` and `body`, does these data the same format? CharField without `max_length`, can we consider it as TextField in serializer?

Comment: Not really. You cannot consider it as textfield because TextField and CharField are generally not represented with the same type in your database (VARCHAR vs TEXT). Practically, databases like MySQL, TEXT, and VARCHAR have the same limit (65k chars)

Comment: You can set a textfield instead charfield in your serializer  without problem I think